# Know of any log display apps similar to Splinter?

Tags: logs

I have been using [Splinter](https://splinter-log.com/#/) for years to display, filter, and search streaming system logs.

The problem is that software is only for Macs.

### Are there any other log display programs like it, that can run on other systems?

EDIT: I have been asked to provide more information.

1. I am looking for an app that displays, filters, and allows for searching of streaming logs, system logs, log dumps, etc.
2. I am interested in free and non-free apps
3. I am interested in software that runs on any OS other than MAC

Answer (score 0):

One solution I have found is [TailExpert](https://tailexpert.neware.nl/) only for Windows.